# How can I call this event from other function?

Tags: c#, function, events, call

How can I call this event `private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){.....}` from like button click function or something?

I've tried `panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);` and couple more but they did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

the Invalidate() Method force the control to repaint.

Comment: If I use Invalidate() Method it kinda clears my panel.

Comment: I used the refresh function and now it works :) I have no idea why but it works.

Comment: fine, have happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as simple function:
`...your_code...; panel1_Paint(null, null); ...your_code...`